# Python: pd.to_datetime deleting all dates

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime, pgadmin

I'm currently downloading a CSV from a database (using PgAdmin) and using a Python script to re-format and filter the rows to import somewhere else. However, I'm experiencing a very strange bug.

If I try running the script using the CSV that I downloaded from the database, it transforms all dates in one of the columns into blanks (NaN). However, if I open that same document in Excel beforehand, and 'Save As' into another CSV file, my script transforms all the dates correctly into the format desired (`dd/mm/yyyy`).

Here's a minimal reproduction case:

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = r'C:\Users\MiguelTavares\Desktop\from_database.csv'
data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
data['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['start_date'], errors='coerce', format='%d/%m/%Y')

print(data)
```

The CSV looks something like this:

```
column1    column2    start_date
test1      test2      26/06/2019
test11     test22     25/07/2019
```

I believe this all happens because I'm passing `errors='coerce'`. However I need to pass this because if I don't I get a ValueError, and I need to put this information into datetime so I can do calculations with it later on.

```
ValueError: time data '2019-06-26' does not match format '%d/%m/%Y' (match)
```

The format (.csv) and encoding (UTF-8) of the CSV files is the same in the file from the database, and the file which I 'Saved As', as well as the content within. So why is my script working perfectly with the duplicate I 'Saved As', but not the one from the database?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't your data format be "%Y%d/%m"?

Comment: But I need it in '%d/%m/%Y' for later, and this works perfectly with one of the CSV files...

Comment: Based upon the error, your dates are already in a proper datetime format, `'2019-06-26'` or contain rows with different formats. `dd/mm/yyyy` is not a proper datetime format, it's a string.

Comment: Hmm, but if I don't transform it into a datetime format, I get the following error later on in the code: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'

Answer (score 0):

Just this should work, if this doesn't work then there is some value in the start_date column with a different format:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep='\s+')
df['start_date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['start_date'])
print(df)

  column1 column2 start_date
0   test1   test2 2019-06-26
1  test11  test22 2019-07-25
```

Comment: Hi, that gives the following error: "pandas._libs.tslibs.np_datetime.OutOfBoundsDatetime: Out of bounds nanosecond timestamp: 3000-12-31 00:00:00"

Comment: Can you post your full CSV somehow?

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

file_path = r'C:\Users\MiguelTavares\Desktop\from_database.csv'

# parse dates while reading csv. dayfirst=True parsing it from format DD/MM
data = pd.read_csv(file_path, parse_dates=['start_date'], dayfirst=True)

print(data)
```

This should work.

Comment: Using this and keeping pd.to_datetime gives me the same result: NaN/blank date cells with the CSV from the database, but everything fine with the same CSV 'Saved As'. 
Using this and removing the pd.to_datetime gives me the following error later in the script: TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'Timestamp'

Comment: I guess there is a inconstant format of dates in the csv from database. The first step should be figuring out, which rows are wrong. Could you please post a link to data.start_date?